# CSS : Applied to adjacent div tag

Tags: html, css

I am getting Test and Hello both in red color however I applied class2 only on 1st div.

Here is my code :

```css
.class1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.class2 {
  color:#F00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="class2">Test</djv>
  <div class="class1">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I am new to CSS. Please help me understand this.

Comment: You made a typo. Voting to close the question as off-topic. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong `</djv>`

See in your code

```css
.class1 {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .class2 {
        color:#F00;
    }
```

```html
<div>
         <div class="class2">Test</div>
         <div class="class1">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that your first div is not closed properly i.e. `</djv>` by mistake you wrote DJV instead